# Error when making a big request to my open distro database

Tags: python, database, docker-compose, python-requests, elasticsearch-opendistro

When I make requests with sizes smaller than 1000000 in the database, it returns me without any problems. However, for higher requests like 3000000 it simply stops in the middle of the process.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
target = sys.argv[1]

headers = {'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
url_get = f'https://localhost:9200/{target}-webenum/_search'
auth=('admin', 'password')

def database():
    print("\n [+] WEBENUM... \n")
    data = {"size": 3000000}
    get_doc = requests.get(url_get, headers=headers, auth=auth, data=json.dumps(data), verify=False)
    print(get_doc.text)
    print("\n [+] END OF database [+] \n")

database()
```

Output:

```
(base) root@root-B350ET2:/root/# python3 teste.py marriott

 [+] database... 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 466, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 461, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1378, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 287, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 466, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 461, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1378, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 287, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root//teste.py", line 39, in <module>
    database()
  File "/root//teste.py", line 35, in database
    get_doc = requests.get(url_get, headers=headers, auth=auth, data=json.dumps(data), verify=False)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Thanks in advance

I've already tried:
Increase the amount of size:

```
   curl --insecure -XPUT --user 'admin':'password' 'https://localhost:9200/marriott-webenum/_settings' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
   "index.max_result_window": "3000000"
}'
```

I increased the amount of RAM in Docker to eight but I had to go back to four:
`- "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx4g -Xms4g"`
In a way it "works" but it crashes my computer and I have to restart it